# Java: Cannot add JDBC driver to class path for MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I'm working in OS X 10.11 if that helps.
So i'm trying to connect the jar file to eclipse. I dragged the file into the package explorer as shown.
Then I went into the build paths and I added the build paths from the folder where they're located.
I also tried doing it externally from another location and that didn't work either.
I also checked the source attachments for each build and added locations

[image]

Comment: Not sure I wanna learn how to use a new IDE at this point.

Comment: I don't think you know how to use the one you have.  Try it in a command shell - no IDE.  That will be one less thing between you and making this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, for some reason I had to go to Run Configurations and then add the jar in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the project in the package explorer.

Select the Built Path

Then select the Configure Build Path from the popup. This will open the properties window.

Now select the library tab

Here you press the button add external jars

Now Browse the jar file and open it.

This will add the jar to your class path.

Comment: Yeah I've done that several combinations. Is the jar file supossed be placed in a certain directory?

Comment: no there is no requirement of the jar file being placed in any specific location. Actually what is problem you are getting?. From your image it appears that the jar has already been included in your project.

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: is what is shown in the image under **Referenced Libraries** ? If not then remove the driver references and follow the steps i have written.

Comment: Yeah, that was under Referenced Libraries

Answer (score 0):

It appears from snapshot that jar has been added twice. Select the build path tab and verify if the jar added twice from two different locations then remove one.